# What is the DSLR equivalent to an EOS film camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I currently have a [Canon EOS 300 film camera](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_300) and want to purchase a digital camera.  What is the equivalent Canon DSLR?

Comment: What about the EOS 300 do you want to be equivalent?

Answer (score 7):

**There is no exact equivalent between film and digital cameras.** Since the EOS 300 was an entry-level film camera, an entry-level digital DSLR may fit your needs. For Canon, those are the Rebel or three-digit (eg, 550D) series. However, your needs may be different.

What about the EOS 300 do you want to be equivalent?

- Canon EOS DSLRs can use the same EF-mount lenses.  Canon mirrorless would require an adapter. What lenses do you currently have? Are they even worth bringing over to digital?
- If you are looking for a camera with the same frame size (and consequently the same angle of view you are used to with any existing lenses), then you would be looking at the EOS 1D, 5D, 6D, and R. Other Canon digital cameras have crop sensors. (Note though that these mentioned models are not entry-level models, and come with a not-insignificant price tag.)
- Must you have a DSLR? Have you considered mirrorless? Canon has EOS-M and EOS-R mirrorless cameras.
- Do you need to stay with Canon? If you're not bringing your old lenses to digital, there's pretty much nothing tying you to Canon except brand loyalty. There are a lot of other great options by different makers that might better fit your needs.

**See also:**

- [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2876/75526)
- [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first "serious" camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67987/75526)
- [What do Pentax and Sigma DSLRs offer that differs from Canon and Nikon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20092/75526)
- [Fujifilm X-T20 vs Pentax K-3 II. Am I missing any significant differences?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100835/75526)

Comment: Very many thanks. I have no loyalty to Canon, wanted to keep the question simple!

Comment: Another thing to consider that I haven't seen mentioned yet is recording time. DLSRs (for import reasons) can only shoot for a maximum of 29m 59s in one go. Depending on your project, just be aware that you may need to do separate takes for things.

Comment: @Sam I think "film" in this question refers to the recording medium, like 35mm, not video/filmography.

Comment: @xiota haha, right you are! My bad. My brain saw "300" and started thinking along the lines of "C-300"....

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, The EOS 300 (known as Rebel in some markets) was replaced by the 'Digital Rebel' some years ago, featuring similar feature set but with an 6.3MP APS-C (smaller than 35mm film) size sensor. Since that time, the 'Rebel' line continues but now features the T7 (or T5, T6) with an 24MP APS-C sensor. So, from a feature set perspective, the T7 is the most likely candidate.

However, others will argue that since your camera is a 35mm film camera, only a 'full frame' camera, with a 35mm sized sensor will fully replace your camera. Your camera was never a 'pro' camera, therefore the closest camera in the Canon line that features 35mm size sensor and is not a 'pro' camera is the Canon EOS 6D.

Unless you KNOW that you must have support for a full-frame (35mm) sensor, your best bet is a T5-T7 model. By the way, your lenses will work with any of these cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Are you considering only new bodies or are used accepteble.

If you can buy used 350d sells for next to nothing but with a 1.6x crop. Alternativly the 5d classic is also rather cheap at no crop.

You can of cource buy better bodies both crop and full frame. For me there seems to be a jump in performance in the 550d for the crop case and with the 5d mark ii for thr full frame case. After that I thing the improvments are more incremental.